# Visualzing the solution of a differential equation with an animation in Julia

Tags: animation, julia

I have solved a system of two second-order differential equations using an implementation of Euler's method in Julia. The below code shows how Euler's method has been called to solve the system in question.

```
θ1 = 1.1900518004210798; θ2 = 0.3807445263738167
f(t, y) = [y[2], -2(y[1] - θ1) - 4y[2] + 0.5sin(3pi*t),
           y[4], -2(y[3] - θ2) - 4(y[4] + abs(y[2])) + 0.5sin(3pi*t)]
y0 = [pi/2, 0, pi/6, 0]; t0 = 0; tFinal = 50; h = 0.001
res = euler(f, y0, t0, tFinal, h)
```

The result, `res`, is a vector of four numbers

```
1.18798735437173    
-0.0458294959470722  
0.31530569612003573 
-0.049213402534541074
```

The first entry is the angle that the bottom line segment forms with the x-axis while the third entry is the angle that the two line segments form with one another (see below figure).

[image]

To create this plot I called `plot_robotarm([res[1], res[3]])` which is implemented according to the below code.

```
function plot_robotarm(thetav)
    # Plots a robotarm with angles thetav
    R = 1;
    xv=zeros(length(thetav)+1)
    yv=zeros(length(thetav)+1)
    for i in 1:length(thetav)
        xv[i+1]=xv[i]+R*cos(thetav[i])
        yv[i+1]=yv[i]+R*sin(thetav[i])
    end
    # Plot with colors 
    opts = (:circle, 10, 1., :blue, stroke(7, 1., :red))
    plt = plot(xv, yv,
               marker = opts,
               c = :red,
               w = 5,
               legend = false,
               xlims = (0, 2.0),
               ylims = (0, 2.0))
    display(plt)
end
```

How can I create an animation that visualizes how consecutive iterations of Euler's method make the robot arm (i.e. the two line segments) move toward the final point at `t = 50`? (I do not need to plot every iteration, just enough so that it makes for an animation that captures the movement of the robot arm.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ffmpeg and Luxor.jl's animation features to make an animated GIF. The frame function needs to be modified to reflect graphical display of each step in your program. See the docs for Luxor for more.

```
using Luxor
using Colors
using BoundaryValueDiffEq

# constants for differential equations and movie
const g = 9.81
const L = 1.0                         # pendulum length in meters
const bobd = 0.10                     # pendulum bob diameter in meters
const framerate = 50.0                # intended frame rate/sec
const t0 = 0.0                        # start time (s)
const tf = 2.3                        # end simulation time (s)
const dtframe = 1.0/framerate         # time increment per frame
const tspan = LinRange(t0, tf, Int(floor(tf*framerate)))  # array of time points in animation

const bgcolor = "black"               # gif background
const leaderhue = (0.80, 0.70, 0.20)  # gif swing arm hue light gold
const hslcolors = [HSL(col) for col in (distinguishable_colors(
                   Int(floor(tf*framerate)+3),[RGB(1,1,1)])[2:end])]
const giffilename = "pendulum.gif"    # output file

# differential equations copied from docs of DifferentialEquations.jl
simplependulum!(du, u, p, t) = (θ=u[1]; dθ=u[2]; du[1]=dθ; du[2]=-(g/L)*sin(θ))
bc1!(residual, u, p, t) = (residual[1] = u[div(end,2)][1] + pi/2; residual[2] = u[end][1] - pi/2)
bvp1 = TwoPointBVProblem(simplependulum!, bc1!, [pi/2,pi/2], (tspan[1],tspan[end]))
sol2 = solve(bvp1, GeneralMIRK4(), dt=dtframe) 

# movie making background
backdrop(scene, framenumber) = background(bgcolor)

function frame(scene, framenumber)
    u1, u2 = sol2.u[framenumber]
    y, x = L*cos(u1), L*sin(u1)
    sethue(leaderhue)
    poly([Point(-4.0, 0.0), Point(4.0, 0.0),
          Point(160.0x,160.0y)], :fill)
    sethue(Colors.HSV(framenumber*4.0, 1, 1))
    circle(Point(160.0x,160.0y), 160bobd, :fill)
    text(string("frame $framenumber of $(scene.framerange.stop)"),
        Point(0.0, -190.0),
        halign=:center)
end

muv = Movie(400, 400, "Pendulum Demo", 1:length(tspan))
animate(muv, [Scene(muv, backdrop),
              Scene(muv, frame, easingfunction=easeinoutcubic)],
              creategif=true, pathname=giffilename)
```